# group_by and compute durbin watson test

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data. I would like to compute the Durbin Watson test for eahc of my time series. Then I am trying to plot the DW values for each company in a boxplot.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(lmtest)

data(FANG)

FANG_annual_returns <- FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
               period     = "daily", 
               type       = "arithmetic")

FANG_annual_returns

FANG_annual_returns %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  summarise(res = dwtest(daily.returns))
```

I am getting a little stuck on the `summarise`, `do`, `map` part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't `dwtest` expect a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `tidyr::nest` and `map`. I used `daily.returns~1` as a formula for `dwtest` and `tidy::broom` to get a clean output.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(lmtest)
library(broom)
FANG_annual_returns %>%
     nest(-symbol) %>%
     mutate(res = map(data, ~broom::tidy(dwtest(daily.returns~1, data=.x)))) %>% 
     unnest(res)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
   symbol data                 statistic  p.value method             alternative                           
    <chr>  <list>                   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>              <chr>                                 
  1 FB     <tibble [1,008 x 2]>      1.98 0.402    Durbin-Watson test true autocorrelation is greater than 0
  2 AMZN   <tibble [1,008 x 2]>      1.98 0.402    Durbin-Watson test true autocorrelation is greater than 0
  3 NFLX   <tibble [1,008 x 2]>      1.80 0.000740 Durbin-Watson test true autocorrelation is greater than 0
  4 GOOG   <tibble [1,008 x 2]>      1.93 0.143    Durbin-Watson test true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Comment: Did something with `nest` but wasn't sure about OP's desired formula. Nesting is a kind of cool feature.

Comment: Indeed, you can see the entire data set in front of you (in few rows) and use `map` as you like.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks!